# @namespaceAccessible class's properties are not accessible from another package

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, namespace, second-generation-packaging

I am trying to create two second-generation (2GP) packages with the same namespace but running into an issue where one of the packages is not able to access the properties of a class from the other package despite the class being annotated with @namespaceAccessible and throwing an error.

```
@namespaceAccessible
public with sharing class AuraResult {

    public Boolean success = false;
    public String message = ''; 

    @namespaceAccessible
    public AuraResult() {

    }

    @namespaceAccessible
    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    @namespaceAccessible
    public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    @namespaceAccessible
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    @namespaceAccessible
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

In the example above, I am able to access the @namespaceAccessible methods i.e., getMessage() and setMessage() methods, but unable to access the properties directly:

```
AuraResult ar = new AuraResult();
String message = ar.getMessage(); // Works
Boolean success = ar.getSuccess(); // Works

message = ar.message; // Throws an error: "Variable is not visible".
success = ar.success; // Throws an error: "Variable is not visible".
```

Using the getter and setter methods is not ideal as it requires a lot of refactoring in my package. Is this expected behavior or a salesforce bug?

Comment: Could you please [edit] to include a minimal reproduction of the issue in code?

Comment: @david Updated the question with sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: This is a [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p3A0000003gpX). Make sure you mark "This affects me" if you want to be updated when this updated.

---

You need to annotate the members if you want them to be directly accessible:

```
@namespaceAccessible public Boolean success = false;
@namespaceAccessible public String message = '';
```

The [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_NamespaceAccessible.htm) specifically state:

> The @namespaceAccessible makes public Apex in a package available to other packages that use the same namespace. **Without this annotation**, Apex classes, methods, interfaces, and **properties** defined in a 2GP package **aren’t accessible** to the other packages with which they share a namespace. Apex that is declared global is always available across all namespaces, and needs no annotation. (emphasis added).

You need to explicitly grant access per member.

Comment: @sfdxfox I should've added this to the question but I was getting "NamespaceAccessible is not allowed on properties" error when I tried to make this change in my package. What I've just realized is that some of my class variables are declared with {get;set;} and these seem to be the ones throwing the error but not the variables without {get;set;}. Not sure if this is the expected behavior.

Comment: @VinodRondla The error doesn't seem to be in line with the documentation. I'll throw a message over at the documentation team, but for now, you'll need to use variables and not properties. You only to use `{get;set;}` anyways if you're writing a Visualforce controller, and you can always use `getX` and `setX` methods as a workaround if you need that capability.

Comment: @VinodRondla This is a Known Issue (added to answer). For now, you'll need to not use properties (i.e. use get/set methods, or find other alternatives).

Comment: @sfdxfox Accepted this as answer and marked "This affects me" on the issue. Thanks for your help.